# Creating an MS Project task with fixed duration and work, but variable resource loading

Tags: ms-project-2013

I have a Microsoft Project 2013 schedule where I would like to have an overall task that takes 100hrs from 3 resources. ResourceA and ResourceB will be fully loaded for 90% of that time. ResourceC is there for support and I only expect him to be used for 10% of effort spread, but used for the full duration of the task.

```
|--------------TASK---------------|  100 hr, 5.6d;
|-------TASK Implementation-------|  90 hr, 5.6; ResourceA[100%], ResourceB[100%]
|-------TASK Support/Review-------|  10 hr, 5.6d; ResourceC[???%]

| Task Name           | Work    | duration | Resource Name        |
| TASK                | 100 hrs | 5.6d     |                      |
| TASK Implementation | 90 hrs  | 5.6d     | ResourceA, ResourceB |
| TASK Suuport/Review | 10 hrs  | 6.6d     | ResouceC [???%]      |
```

Creating the task for ResourceA and ResourceB is straightforward. But, how do I create a task for ResourceC where it is fixed to the start and stop of the other task and the loading of ResourceC is variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create the support task in Manual Scheduling mode
2. Without doing anything else, assign your support resource to the task at 10% loading. If you don't do this before the next step then it won't work
3. Go to the start date of the "primary" task, Ctrl-C to copy it, then go to the Start Date for the support task. Right click->Paste Special->Paste Link. This will link the start date of the support task to the start date of the "primary" task. Repeat for the End Dates

You will now find that if the start and end dates of the "primary" task move, the Support task will track them and it will keep the resource loaded at 10% no matter what the actual duration of the Support Task. Show the Work column to prove to yourself that this is true by modifying the start/end date of the "primary" task and observing the Support Task change and the workload of the Support Resource to change to match workload equal to 10% of the primary duration.